# Is RabbitMQ basic_publish asynchronous?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have the following Producer code.

**message** is a dict data obtained after some computations. I want to publish **message** to a queue. Then I reset **message** to an empty dict for some other calculations. But the consumer is always getting an empty dict from the queue. I feel **message** is reset before it is published(is it asynchronous?). How to make it synchronous ?

```
message = {a big dict ...}
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                            routing_key='my_queue',
                            body=json.dumps(message))
message = {}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `channel.basic_publish` is async, and it is correct in this way.

`channel.basic_publish` does not wait the insert time, otherwise, It'd be slow.

you should change the way how you handle your messages, 
**but** if you want to make is synchronous you can use the transactions.

should be something like:

```
channel.tx_select
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                            routing_key='my_queue',
                            body=json.dumps(message))
channel.tx_commit
```

**Note** transaction can drop the performances.

[Read here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/) for more detail